# How To Find MainActivity Of Facebook Lite Apk . Because It Was not Available In His Location

Tags: binding, payload, metasploit

How do I find the MyActivity Smali file of Facebook Lite?
It is not in the location given by APK tool. It is hidden.MainActivity is Required For Mannual Payload Binding Prossess.How can I find it? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to \smali\com\facebook\lite
You will see 4 items:

```
Pretos
ClientApplicationSplittedShell.smali
LiteClassPreloaderDelegate.smali
{METASPLOIT FOLDER WITH ANY RANDOM NAME}
```

There you will get all you files with their names changed...

Answer (score 0):

go to Documents\APK Easy Tool\1-Decompiled APKs\Facebook\smali\com\facebook\katana\liteprovider